# Install part of a pypi library with poetry

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-poetry

Does anyone know if I can install a python library's submodule with poetry? I can install with pip

`pip install library_a[sub_library]`

How can I do this in poetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that in poetry you can use

`poetry add "library_a[sub_library]"`

Make sure to add the quote `"` to make it work.